# Override virtual method to change UI

Tags: c#, ios, overriding, xamarin, virtual

I've got a BaseController that is in a Library and contains the methods for a TableView, like RowsInSection, RowSelected and GetCell. In the GetCell method I modified some elements like `TextField.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;`

I need to put them in a `public virtual` so I can override them from my ViewController, if the elements need to be styled (I don't want to change anything in the Library).

How can I put the styling like TextAlignment in a virtual and how can I override the method from my ViewController? I'm stuck with what needs to be returned..

I got this so far in the Library:

```
public virtual void SetAlignment()
{
    TextField.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
}
```

This is my code in the ViewController:

```
public override void SetAlignment ()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("SetAlignment Overrided");
}
```

Comment: looks good to me... What doesn't work?

Comment: My output is indeed `SetAlignment Overrided` but how can I for example change the `UITextAlignment` with that override method to set it to `Left`?

Comment: In case you can access TextField (e.g. not private) just use TextField.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
If TextField is private (a field) use an property to access it (you would have to define the property in your library)

Comment: The TextField is `public` but it is created inside the BaseController. I get an `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the `override` method.

Comment: Looks like TextField gets assigend in your BaseController but the assignment got overridden in your ViewController...

Comment: It is working, forgot an old reference to `SetAlignment()` in my `ViewDidLoad()`. Thanks a lot!